# Thread Timeout in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

In application i am using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with pool size 4. I am scheduling my tasks on pool one by one and want to add thread time out for each task. I tried with Future object that is returned after submitting task as in given code.

```
Future<Integer> future = service.submit(() -> {System.out.println("Current Running Thread "+Thread.currentThread());
```

but on calling `future.get()` it blocks the thread until result is not returned.
Because of that Main thread is not able to execute further task.
I want to submit each task with specified thread timeout so that if execution happens before timeout then fine else execution should stop and thread should be back to threadpool releasing all resources.
I tried with `CompletableFuture` too but for no use.

Comment: What language is that? Java?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you tried and what worked and what not when using `CompletableFuture` as this is a viable approach.

Comment: Isn't it considered a bad practice to terminate a thread forcefully in Java?

Comment: Hi Freakish, I am using java to implement the feature.

Comment: Hi Michid, I tried with CompletableFuture but didn't get expected result.

Comment: Hi Janez, You are right. It's not a good practice to timeout a thread.